# Python HTTP Request Login on Granasocial

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Trying to login on this website:

> http://www.granasocial.com

Code:

```
def adiciona_links():
    with requests.Session() as c:
        URL = "http://www.granasocial.com/painel/"
        EMAIL="email@email.com"
        PASSWORD="password"
        c.get(URL)
        login_data = dict(email=EMAIL,password=PASSWORD)
        c.post(URL,data=login_data,headers={'Referer':"http://www.granasocial.com/"})
        page = c.get("http://www.granasocial.com/painel/")
        print page.content
```

But this function returning login page response, not painel response.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

First disable JavaScript in browser (because `requests` doesn't use javascript) and then observe browser behavior when you login to the page. Chrome and Firefox has very helpful tool called "Developer Tools".

Use it and you can see:

1. browser redirects "http://www.granasocial.com/painel/" to 
   "http://www.granasocial.com/login.php"
2. login form sends data to "http://www.granasocial.com/login.php"
3. login form sends

   `email:your_email`
   `senha:your_password`

   there is no field named `password`

You have to try harder to login on this page ;)